# Cannot remove inline styles after applying

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I use custom format presets to apply bold / italic via the inline styles:

```
formats: {
    bold: {inline: 'span', selector: 'span,a,sub,sup', styles: {fontWeight: 'bold'}},
    italic: {inline: 'span', selector: 'span,a,sub,sup', styles: {fontStyle: 'italic'}},
}
```

After both of the formats are applied to the selected text, there's no possibility to turn off them: if a user clicks on the 'Bold' or 'Italic' button, it doesn't become 'unpressed' and the corresponding format is not removed. This problem occurs only when more than one word is selected.

Maybe there are some options to fine-tune TinyMce behavior when removing format?

(UPD):

TinyMCE Fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/BVfaab

Tested in Chrome 59.0.3071.104 for Linux.

Comment: Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows your complete configuration so people can see this in action?  What browser(s) are you using in your testing?

Comment: Added link to Fiddle and browser description

Comment: How are you applying the style?  I don't see any UI element in that fiddle that would allow me to apply the style.

Comment: I'm using standard "B" and "I" toolbar buttons.

Comment: I would open an issue on the TinyMCE GitHub Issue Tracker for this:  https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues  I would think this is some sort of bug in TinyMCE.  I would note that its not selecting two words but the entire paragraph that causes this for me.  If I add more words to your sentence I can select multiple words without issue and turn bold on/off.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration! I agree with you that this is a bug in TinyMCE so it would be great if you open an issue and it will be fixed some day in future versions.